# Navigation property doesn't get loaded - EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm having 3 models Items, Branches and ItemsInBranches defined as follows

```
public class Items
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SizeId { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int DiscountId { get; set; }
    public int ShortageMargin { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public double ActualPrice
    {
        get
        {
            double amount = ((double)Price * (double)Discount.Amount / 100);
            double price = (Price - amount < 0) ? 0 : Price - amount;
            return price;
        }
    }

    public Discounts Discount { get; set; }
    public ItemSizes Size { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemsInBranches> ItemsInBrach { get; set; }
}

public class Branches
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employees> Employees { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TransactionLog> TransacionLogs { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemsInBranches> ItemsInBranch { get; set; }
}

public class ItemsInBranches
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsShort
    {
        get
        {
            return Amount < Item.ShortageMargin;
        }
    }

    public Items Item { get; set; }
    public Branches Branch { get; set; }
}
```

whenever I try to load items in branches using the following code I Branch navigation property gets loaded just fine but I the Items is always set to null

```
    public IEnumerable<StorageViewModel> GetStorage(int? BranchId)
    {
        var storage = Find(x => true).Select(s => new StorageViewModel
        {
            Amount = s.Amount,
            BranchName = s.Branch.Name,
            ItemName = s.Item.Name,
            SortageMargin = s.Item.ShortageMargin,
            IsShort = s.IsShort
        });
        return storage;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dataContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
    }
```

I made sure the ItemId and BranchId are set to foreign keys for the Items and Branches tables in the database, they don't allow nulls and they enforce foreign key constraints
could anyone tell me why only the Branch get loaded while Item is always set to null

Comment: Did you by any chance leave out constructor code for brevity?

Comment: You mean ItemName and SortageMargin are null?

Comment: At the moment, you're relying on lazy loading to fetch related entities (Branch, Item) from the database for each `ItemsInBranches` separately. Both properties are not `virtual` so I'm surprised that `Branch` seems to load and *not* surprised that `Item` doesn't. But you should return `IQueryable` from `Find` to make the projection both work and be useful (i.e. restricting the amount of data). Deal with `IsShort` later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you shouldn't try to wrap frameworks, particularly EF with helper methods like you're doing with your `Find` method, which I mention because that is why you're running into this problem (rather it's making the solution harder than it would otherwise have to be without the helper).

You may run into this problem you ran into (or where you want to specify `AsNoTracking()` in your `Find` one day when you find out about the `ChangeTracker` and how it works and `SaveChanges()` starts running slow or you have a large memory footprint due to having too much attached at once.  Of course this is problem more with EF because it makes it too easy for people to develop without really understanding important concepts like transactions - the details of the layer it's trying to abstract away...)

You would need to load related entities somehow.  [I'd recommend reading this link and choosing an option.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)  Here's one option on that link that only touches your `GetStorage` method, which might "solve the problem easily" but may not be good performance-wise if there are a lot of records - considering your predicate is including everything, though, there may not be a lot.  I can't give you a better recommendation without seeing more of your code.  If it's loading one and not the other and they're otherwise identical (same non-nullable FK and there's a corresponding record) then I think it's probably configuration somewhere... again read the link to see how to configure loading of navigation properties.  Note this will probably generate multiple `SELECT` statements; I couldn't think of a better way (besides dropping down into `Set<>`) with the constraints of using `Find` inside `GetStorage` to grab the missing records you needed.  If you could call the `Find` from a different class that has a different `TEntity` specified then you could probably get just the `Items` records you need in one SELECT statement - but I don't know how you're setting up your services and their lifecycles.  That might be a compromise between performance and not having a mass-refactoring of the data access wrappers.

```
var allEntities = Find(x => true).ToList();
allEntities.ForEach(x => _dataContext.Entry(x).Reference(y => y. Item).Load());
var storage = allEntities.Select(s => new StorageViewModel
// ...
```

`GetStorage` seems like it's specific to one `TEntity`; Your `Find` method seems like it has `TEntity` defined as a generic in the containing class - so if I had to guess those methods are in (2) different classes even though you put them back-to-back.  Your `Find` method is then probably on a class that abstracts away EF to give you a "simpler" interface to the database.  EF is already that simple interface to the database; you don't need another.

What you could be doing instead is making concrete repositories that take a hard dependency on specific `TEntity`'s and depend on a `DbContext` and then having either your domain logic taking a dependency on your repositories (which would require you to mock the repository somehow - either with a pseudo database, actual database or a leaky in-memory database to "unit" test your domain logic) or having your repositories totally de-coupled from your domain logic, enabling fast-executing domain logic unit tests.  Then your repositories have shielded the rest of the application from EF, so you could change it out to ADO.NET or a lighter weight ORM like Dapper.

A `Find` method like that is an EF abstraction - you've tied whatever depends on that to EF (and your schema, probably) even if you didn't realize it.  What I briefly described is true a database abstraction - which actually would free you up to change your data access (and schema) if you needed to - just change out the repository implementation without changing its API or behavior...

Comment: Though it may be true what you're saying here, the OP wasn't asking for an architectural review. Never mind if you add it for free, but then you should also adequately address the direct question. `Include` doesn't help here, because the OP's problem is in a projection.

Comment: @GertArnold I agreed with what you said; I thought I answered the question and I was trying to explain why OP got in the situation for having the question in the first place (coding oneself into a corner).  It looks like once you call `Find` you have an `IEnumerable<>`, not a `DbSet<>` so it's too late to call `Include` at that point.  OP could do what will be a separate query, I suppose, if OP wants the "fix" to happen only inside the `GetStorage`... I can add that to my answer.

Comment: @GertArnold Alright I edited my answer.  If you have any more constructive feedback you would like to give, I would appreciate it!

Comment: @Scarnet I am very cautious myself about "fixing" architecture - I'll continue the "wrong pattern" over making things confusing for people or having lots of different patterns floating around in the codebase.  There are often times real world constraints (sometimes coming from people who would remove them if they knew better...), but still you can't change the things you can't change, so let me know if my solution does fit your specific constraints.  Actual real world constraints are more important than ideals - my rant was more applicable, perhaps, to the future, not present.